# Differencing, taking logs or squaring does not fix nonstationarity. What to do?

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-transformation, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I want to test for correlation in a time series model. However, all four independent variables and the dependent variable are non-stationary. I tried taking first, second and third differences but my dependent variable remains non-stationary. I also tried transforming it into a squared variable or logarithm, but the altered variables were still non-stationary according to the augmented Dickey-Fuller test. What else can I do?

Raw data regarding:

My dependent variable the intra-EU trade share (exports)
[image]

An independent variable, the number of EU Civil law regulations
[image]

An independent variable, the number of EU Healthcare regulations
[image]

An independent variable, the number of EU Environment regulations
[image]

An independent variable, the number of national court judgements in which EU regulations were used.
[image]

Comment: Could you include a plot of the original time series?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Remco.  Your question is vague.  Why is it important to find a transformation that makes any of the variables appear stationary?  What kind of "test for correlation" are you contemplating and how do you hope it will help you with the modeling?

Comment: Okay thanks for the comments, I am new to this site. @whuber I want to test for correlation between the independent variables and the dependent variable with the lm command in R, so a linear regression. However I feel like my results are inflated because all variables, both dependent and the independent ones are non stationary. Tomorrow I can include the plots of the variables over time.

Comment: That's interesting, because the cure you are proposing--that is, possibly applying nonlinear transformations--*totally* changes the meaning of this model and therefore might be worse than the apparent problem you are trying to address.  When you edit your post tomorrow it would help to provide some context for that problem, your assumptions, and your objectives.

Comment: @whuber I added the plots of raw data. My aim is to assess whether there is a correlation between the dependent variable and the independent variables. The theory behind my regression provides me with some space in a sense that I could include lagged variables but still I would be faced with non stationarity of the independent and dependent variables.